# Python import leads to [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application, though import works in `cmd`

Tags: python, anaconda, xgboost

I have installed [XGBoost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost) on Windows 10 today, and it works well when I import it in `python` running in a common `cmd` prompt.

But when I use Jupyter Notebook or the Anaconda Prompt and Python, it shows the error `[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`.

I have tried `where python` in `cmd` and `anaconda prompt`, and that's the same.
I also have tried to print `sys.path` in Python, and that's the same too.

Comment: when i open `jupyter notebook` in `cmd` , i can import xgboost again.

Comment: i found that when i open jupyter in windows start menu,it could't work.And when i copy it to anywhere,and open it in a folder , it can work.So,what caused this?

Comment: I experienced the same issue when trying to do ``import mxnet`` in Python 3.7.1 on Windows 10. However, if I open the environment's prompt using the conda navigator, everything works fine. Would be helpful to know the reason.

Comment: I found out that there is a difference in the `PATH` environment variable. I compared the output of `echo %PATH%` from the Anaconda Prompt (opened using the Start Menu link) to the one opened in the Anaconda Navigator (clicking on the 'play' button right next to the environment. The following entries in PATH were missing in my case: `C:\tools\Anaconda3;C:\tools\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\tools\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\tools\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\tools\Anaconda3\Scripts;`

After adding them, I could successfully do `import mxnet`.